# Problem retrieving picture from Camera intent in other than myself device (Oreo)

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I am trying to get image from camera intent. Its working nice but only in my device (oreo / 8.1.0). I generate unsigned apk and tried to run in other device (pie and lolipop)but its not working.

I search stackoverflow and other sites, but people asked question about "camera intent problem in lolipop". My question is something different (I think).

I tried to check sdk version and apply different code. I.e. as per one answer from stackoverflow I used this code `Picasso.get().load(file).into(imageView);` instead of `Picasso.get().load(photoURI).into(imageView);` in LOLIPOP but its not working.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null; // Create the File where the photo should go
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                tempPhoto = photoFile;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.package.appname.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                tempPhoto = photoFile;
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
```

Code for createImageFile function:

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Receiving result here

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        try {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);

                Picasso.get().load(file).into(imageView);

//                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
//                        .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
//                if (bitmap != null) {
//                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//                }
            } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me to give accurate result in all sdk versions? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never seem to set `mCurrentPhotoPath`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated my code. Please check.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you are holding onto `mCurrentPhotoPath` in your saved instance state `Bundle`, as your process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Camera/FileProvider) shows how to take pictures with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, though I then show the image using `ACTION_VIEW` where you would load it into your `ImageView` using Picasso. Also, I recommend passing a `File` to Picasso for a filesystem path, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        try {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData(); // you need take uri of image
        imageView.setImageURI(uri); // you don't need of picasso to load local images     


           //     Picasso.get().load(file).into(imageView);

//                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
//                        .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
//                if (bitmap != null) {
//                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//                }
            } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why but when I put `Uri uri = intent.getData();` this line at above said location and imageview not loading the picture.